# Is it possible to get the time from DIV to other page? How?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<?php $date = date('m-d-Y'); ?>

<form class="signin" method="POST" action="2ndpage.php">
<h1>Validate</h1>
<input name="date" type="text" autocomplete="on" id="calendar" value="<?php echo $date ?>" />

<div id="rtime"></div>
<button type="submit">Next page</button>
```

2nd page:

```
$d = $_POST['date'];
$t = $_POST['mytime'];
```

The $d output the date I want but the $t it returns that it's undefined index.

The "rtime" is a running time (Javascript) and but that's not the problem. The problem is how to get the value of div ("rtime") will be displayed to the next page that I can be used. More likely to say I want to make a report of a user's transaction and put the date and time.

Confused. Please help.

Comment: All you are missing is a form control (input field?) with the name `mytime`. See my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden input field.

```
<form class="signin" method="POST" action="2ndpage.php" onsubmit="update_time()">
<h1>Validate</h1>
<input name="date" type="text" autocomplete="on" id="calendar" value="<?php echo $date ?>" />
<input name="mytime" type="hidden" id="mytime">
```

Then in the Javascript, the `onsubmit` handler can copy from the `rtime` DIV to this field.

```
function update_time() {
    document.getElementById('mytime').value = document.getElementById('rtime').innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if you are missing an `input element` called `mytime`.

```
<?php
  $date = date('m-d-Y');
  $time = date('H:i');
?>
<input name="date" type="text" autocomplete="on" id="calendar" value="<?php echo $date ?>" />
<input name="mytime" type="text" autocomplete="on" id="calendar" value="<?php echo $time ?>" />
```

Comment: I don't think `mytime` is a user-supplied input, he wants it to come from the `rtime` div.

Comment: Thanks to you both.

Yes, I want it that way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the value you want was generated by JavaScript you can either:

Have JavaScript insert that value until a hidden input in your form

Or use Ajax. Jquery is nice.

Answer (score 0):

$t in 2ndpage.php is undefined because (on your first page) there is no `<input>` field with the name `mytime`.

The $d value is retrieved because this:

```
$d = $_POST['date'];
```

matches up with this (note the `name=` parameter):

```
<input name="date" value="<?php echo $date ?>" />
```

For the $t to show up, you need this (again, note the `name=` parameter):

```
<input name="mytime" value="time_goes_here">
```

---

When a form is POSTED to another PHP file, each `name` becomes the name of a variable, and the `value` stored in the element becomes the value of the variable on the other side.

You can retrieve these "variables" through $_POST:

- You must create a NEW variable in the 2nd PHP file (it is common to use exactly the same name as on the first page - that is, the `name` parameter from the element)
- the variable's value is retrieved via the $_POST command, referencing the `name` from Page 1:

  $thetime = $_POST['mytime'];

---

To pass a value through that DIV, you can use jQuery to insert an `<input>` element with a `name` into the DIV before the form is submitted.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('button').click(function() {
                    //Next line adds a hidden field `mytime` with text value
                    //$('#rtime').html('<input name="mytime" value="Two oclock">');

                    //Below adds hidden field `mytime` with current time string
                    var d = new Date();
                    var h = d.getHours();
                    var m = d.getMinutes();
                    var s = d.getSeconds();
                    var strTime = h+':'+m+':'+s;
                    //alert(strTime);
                    $('#rtime').html('<input name="mytime" value="'+strTime+'">');
                    //return false;

                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <?php $date = date('m-d-Y'); ?>

    <form class="signin" method="POST" action="test108b.php">
    <h1>Validate</h1>
    <input name="date" type="text" id="calendar" value="<?php echo $date ?>" />

    <div id="rtime" name="mytime"></div>
    <button type="submit">Next page</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem of the missing `mtime` input?

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden input with name `mytime`

```
<input id="mytime" name="mytime" type="hidden" />
```

and now your JavaScript timer have to set value in that input

```
$("#mytime").val(actual_time);
```